# Chance of Hamiltonian Path in Sudoku cell

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Checking the correctness of a daily Sudoku I'd just finished, I noticed a curious pattern in one of the 3x3 cells:

```
1 9 3
8 2 4
7 6 5
```

Note that each of the numbers is adjacent in the 8 cardinal directions to the number immediately above and below it, so you can traverse them in order without skipping any.  This is certainly not always the case.  Consider:

```
1 2 3
5 6 4
7 8 9
```

This has a gap between the 4 and 5, so there's no complete path here.  I made a mental note to check it in subsequent puzzles to see if it happened again - it seems pretty rare.  Even with nine 3x3 grids on each puzzle, once per day for over a month, I've yet to find another.  Also, the original is especially unusual as it creates a Hamiltonian Cycle, not just a Path, as the 1 and the 9 are also adjacent.  This also isn't always true.  Consider:

```
1 2 3
6 5 4
7 8 9
```

This has a Hamiltonian Path from 1-9, but not a Cycle because the ends aren't adjacent.  My question is, in a 3x3 grid, how many of the possible `(3x3)!` permutations result in a Hamiltonian Path, and how many of those are also Hamiltonian Cycles?  Is there a formula for these that can be generalized to 4x4, 5x5, or other NxN grids?  (3x3 is the minimum, as with 2x2, the answer is trivially 100%, since all numbers are adjacent to eachother.)

Cycles seem easiest to pin down, at least in 3x3.  There's basically two shapes as far as I can tell, one with no diagonal crossing and one with:  (Apologies for crude ASCII art)

```
1 2 3  ┌────/    1 2 3  ┌────┐
9 4 5  │  /─┐    9 7 4  │ /\/
8 7 6  └────┘    8 5 6  │/ /\
```

which can be rotated and flipped into 8 configurations each, and then for each configuration, the numbers can be cycled into one of 9 positions, or reversed for another 9.  So you get `2 x 8 x 9 x 2 = 288`.  I have more difficulty figuring out all of the non-Cyclic paths, or coming up with a generalized solution for larger grids.

Comment: There is a 2 to 1 correspondence between permutations that make a path and paths you can draw in an mxn grid (pick an endpoint to be 1, and write numbers sequentially along the path). There is a 2mn to 1 correspondence between permutations that make a cycle and cycles you can draw in an mxn grid (pick any point to be 1, pick a direction, and write numbers sequentially along the cycle). So really, you just need to count paths and cycles on an unlabeled rectangular grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are OEIS sequences [A158651](https://oeis.org/A158651) for paths and [A140519](https://oeis.org/A140519) for cycles (where the latter needs to be multiplied by $2N^2$ since they only count the cycles and not their realisations through permutations of numbers). The entries refer to the paper [Enumerating Hamiltonian Cycles](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v21i4p7/0) by Ville H. Pettersson in the Electronic Journal of Combinatorics, Volume $21$, Issue $4$, $2014$.

Comment: A140519 also links to [A140521](https://oeis.org/A140521), which is the same only doubled for N>1.  So you'd just need to multiply that by $N^2$ to account for different starting positions on the loop.  Then of course you'd need to divide by $N^2!$ to find the actual chance.  For a 3x3 board, that comes to 0.29%  That times 9 for the 9 cells in a Sudoku board means each puzzle has a ~2.66% chance of a Hamiltonian path/cycle.  @Fahrbach's solution covers some smaller non-square boards, but this one is pretty definitive for squares, so I'd say this is the more complete answer.

Answer (score 5):

I just wrote a program to test the following $m \times n$ boards. The coordinates are (paths from 1 to $mn$, cycles).

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
m \backslash n & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline \\
1 & (1,1) & (2,2) & (2,0) & (2,0) & (2, 0) \\
2 & (2,2) & (24,24) & (96,48) & (416,128) & (1536,320) \\
3 & (2,0) & (96,48) & (784,288) &  \\
4 & (2,0) & (416,128) & & \\
5 & (2,0) & (1536,320)\\
\end{array}

Comment: Okay, so I guess this answers the 3x3 case.  (Glad to see my calculation for Cycles was correct.)  How difficult would it be to generalize this to larger grids?  I suspect that the runtime for such a program would get prohibitively expensive after a certain point...

Comment: Oh, and for reference, are you counting cycles as paths?  Or would the total for paths actually be 784 + 288?

Comment: The paths include the cycles. I'm about to update this for arrays of size $m\times n$. The runtime of this program is $O((mn)!)$, so we can't push it too far.

Comment: You could cut the time in half by only doing cases where `M >= N`, since the results for MxN should obviously be identical to NxM.  I think there's probably a more optimal solution - rather than testing every permutation, start with one spot and do a traversal, cutting short any path which isolates a point or points, thus saving unneeded calculation.